# The event click does not work after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a list of personal loaded in page when i click to an element of the list i display it information ; the click run very well but when i click in a button to filter this list for example to display in this list the developer personal the click to display information does not fire.

i forgot to tell you i have done this

```
        $("ul").on("click", "li a", function() {
            console.log("clicked");
        });
```

but still not working

```
            <ul class="mail-list">
                <li class="mail-list-item">
                    <a class="mail-list-link" href="#show">
                        <div class="mail-list-name">John</div>
                        <div class="mail-list-content">
                            <span class="mail-list-subject">Developer</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="mail-list-item">
                    <a class="mail-list-link" href="#show">
                        <div class="mail-list-name">Mike</div>
                        <div class="mail-list-content">
                            <span class="mail-list-subject">Designer</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

javascript

```
'use strict';

(function ($) {
'use strict';

var Mail = {
    Constants: {
        MEDIA_QUERY_BREAKPOINT: '992px'
    },
    CssClasses: {
        MAIL_LIST: 'mail-list',
        MAIL_LIST_ITEM: 'mail-list-item',
        MAIL_LIST_LINK: 'mail-list-link',
        MAIL_CONTENT: 'mail-content',
        ACTIVE: 'active',
        HOVER: 'hover'
    },
    init: function init() {
        this.$window = $(window);
        this.$list = $('.' + this.CssClasses.MAIL_LIST);
        this.$items = $('.' + this.CssClasses.MAIL_LIST_ITEM);
        this.$links = $('.' + this.CssClasses.MAIL_LIST_LINK);
        this.$content = $('.' + this.CssClasses.MAIL_CONTENT);
        this.$backBtns = this.$content.find('[data-toggle="tab"]');
        this.breakpoint = null;
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function bindEvents() {
        this.$items.on('mouseenter.e.mail', this.handleItemMouseEnter.bind(this));
        this.$items.on('mouseleave.e.mail', this.handleItemMouseLeave.bind(this));

        this.$links.on('click.e.mail', this.handleLinkClick.bind(this));
        this.$links.add(this.$backBtns).on('shown.bs.tab', this.handleTabShown.bind(this));
        $("ul").on("click", "li a", function() {
            console.log("clicked");
        });
        this.breakpoint = window.matchMedia('(max-width: ' + this.Constants.MEDIA_QUERY_BREAKPOINT + ')');
        this.breakpoint.addListener(this.handleMediaQueryChange.bind(this));
    },
    handleItemMouseEnter: function handleItemMouseEnter(evt) {
        $(evt.currentTarget).addClass(this.CssClasses.HOVER);
    },
    handleItemMouseLeave: function handleItemMouseLeave(evt) {
        $(evt.currentTarget).removeClass(this.CssClasses.HOVER);
    },
    handleLinkClick: function handleLinkClick(evt) {
        var $link = $(evt.currentTarget),
        $item = $link.closest('.' + this.CssClasses.MAIL_LIST_ITEM);

        if ($item.hasClass(this.CssClasses.ACTIVE)) $item.removeClass(this.CssClasses.ACTIVE);

        this.rememberScrollbarPos();
    },
    handleTabShown: function handleTabShown(evt) {

        var $trigger = $(evt.currentTarget),
        $activeLink = this.getActiveLink();

        if (!$trigger.is($activeLink)) {
            this.scrollTo(this.rememberedScrollbarPos());
            } else {
            this.scrollTo(0);
        }
    },
    handleMediaQueryChange: function handleMediaQueryChange(evt) {
        var $target = this[this.mediaQueryMatches() ? 'getBackBtn' : 'getActiveLink']();

        $target.length && $target.trigger('click');
    },
    mediaQueryMatches: function mediaQueryMatches() {
        return this.breakpoint.matches;
    },
    rememberScrollbarPos: function rememberScrollbarPos() {
        this.ypos = this.$window.scrollTop();
    },
    rememberedScrollbarPos: function rememberedScrollbarPos() {
        return this.ypos;
    },
    getActiveItem: function getActiveItem() {
        return this.$items.filter('.' + this.CssClasses.ACTIVE);
    },
    getActiveMail: function getActiveMail() {
        return this.$content.filter('.' + this.CssClasses.ACTIVE);
    },
    getActiveLink: function getActiveLink() {
        var $activeItem = this.getActiveItem();
        return $activeItem.find('[data-toggle="tab"]');
    },
    getBackBtn: function getBackBtn() {
        var $activeMail = this.getActiveMail();
        return $activeMail.find('[data-toggle="tab"]');
    },
    scrollTo: function scrollTo(ypos) {
        this.$window.scrollTop(ypos);
    }
};

Mail.init();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).on("click")` event here

```
$(document).on("click",".mail-list-link",function() {
// code
});
```

Comment: where i put it in the code ? because i replaced the $("ul").on("click", "li a", function() { by yours it does'nt work

Comment: the problem is i need the other functions handleLinkClick, handleTabShown ... i can't do this

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click",".mail-list-link",function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
// code
});
```

Maybe the link is following href so try this.